# Safari 10 does not cache images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, caching, web, safari

I have an ASP.NET MVC website hosted on Azure AppService, and I am trying to enable the caching of dynamic images (served with help of the Controller#File() method) on client-side. I used a few techniques to achieve that:

1. Converted the query string based URL into the "classic" URL, e.g.

   /file/i/Supplier/Logo/fed88a06-1157-4bbb-826d-365bdd8c89eb/png/cng.png

I am using the IIS Rewrite module to convert it back to the query string based URL.

2. Added the following attribute to the action method which returns the image:

   ```
   [OutputCache(Duration = 31536000, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
   //31536000 seconds represent one year
   ```

   3. Finally I forced the 304 status on all image requests where the If-Modified-Since header contains a date occurring less than 300 days ago (the images do not change often).

It works in all web browsers except Safari 10 and iOS 10. The images are being cached fine in Sarafi 9, 8, 7, iOS 8.3.3, Chrome, Edge, Firefox but in Safari 10 they are almost never get cached (on iOS 10 too but it is not that important). This condition can be reproduced on two physical Mac laptops as well as on the Mac VM on BrowserStack. Caching in Safari is **not** disabled.

Is there anything special about Apple's latest web browsers that they don't cache  resources as expected? Or, am I doing anything wrong?

I don't know how to review request and response headers in Safari (is it possible at all?) but in Chrome the request and response headers are as follow.

I removed the Host, Referrer and Cookie headers for clarity.

**The first run**

*Request*

```
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,sr;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
```

*Response*

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=31533495
Content-Length:32300
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Mon, 17 Oct 2016 14:58:59 GMT
Expires:Tue, 17 Oct 2017 14:17:13 GMT
Last-Modified:Mon, 17 Oct 2016 14:17:13 GMT
Vary:*
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

**The second run**

*Request*

```
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,sr;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
If-Modified-Since:Mon, 17 Oct 2016 14:17:12 GMT
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
```

*Response*

```
Request URL:http://******/file/i/Supplier/Logo/1f70c0ac-309c-4629-9186-6ee1b3700d3e/png/crown-logo.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

Cache-Control:private, max-age=31533237
Date:Mon, 17 Oct 2016 15:03:15 GMT
Expires:Tue, 17 Oct 2017 14:17:12 GMT
Last-Modified:Mon, 17 Oct 2016 14:17:12 GMT
Vary:*
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```